# How to select a dropdown cell validation value

Tags: excel, vba, validation

I'm attempting to select a value within a data validation in an Excel sheet.

```vb
Set r = Sheets("DASHBOARD").Cells.Find(What:="Selection Location ->", LookAt:=xlWhole, searchorder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
r.Offset(0, 1).Select
With Selection.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
      xlBetween, Formula1:="=List1"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
```

My "List1" comes from a `Names.Add` within a range defined in the lines above.
Now that this list is created, I want Excel to select and display the new first value in my data validation, or any value I so choose in the code.

I can't find anything on accessing a data validation through VBA.
I can copy/paste the value I would like in the `target.cell`, however then the data validation disappears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’ve just noticed this question, and it reminds of a project I did recently where a very long validation list of ‘sites’ was broken down by ‘regions’ to reduce the amount of scrolling a user had to do.  The relevance to your question is that – once a region had been selected , then a new validation list is stipulated by the code **and the first new value on that list is displayed.**

I’ve marked the relevant line of code thus: “<-THIS LINE”.  You should be able to tweak the code to suit your needs.  If this isn’t what you were after, just comment so I can delete the answer.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim MyList As String
If Not Intersect(Range("L3"), Target) Is Nothing Then

 With Sheet3.Range("L4:N4")  'These are merged cells 
    .ClearContents
    .Validation.Delete
        MyList = Sheet3.Range("L3").Value
    .Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, Formula1:="=" & MyList
End With

Sheet3.Buttons("Button1").Caption = MyList

With Sheet3.Range("L4")
    .Value = Sheet4.Range(MyList).Cells(1, 1).Value  '<-THIS LINE
End With

End If
End Sub
```

Comment: That's awesome, I had no idea you could reference a list like that. Very helpful!